# How to convert physical server to Azure VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, azure, physical-to-virtual

I am running Windows 2008 R2 on physical server (Dell Machine). Now I want to convert the physical server to Azure VM. I have tried with disk2vhd utility but I am getting the below error while creating a Azure custom image by using VHD.

```
Error: The VHD has an unsupported virtual size of 250000000000 bytes. The size must be a whole number (in MBs).
```

Is there any document is available to convert physical server to Azure VM?

Answer (score 2):

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/62d03380-41e5-4be8-a742-431a980bc318/csupload-produces-unknown-error-unsupported-virtual-size?forum=windowsazuredata

Looks like it needs to be a whole number in MB.  Dividing your number by 1024 two times (to reduce to KB, and then MB) doesn't result in a whole number.  According to the thread you just need to resize it.